# Approaches to prevent submitting a modern create/edit forms if a status = close while a date field is missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, validation, modern-experience

I am working on a sharepoint online custom list, and the list contain these 2 main fields:-

1. Status. drop-down with options; new,open,closed
2. Publish Date.

now i want to prevent users from creating/editing an item and change its "Status" to "Closed" unless they specify a value for the "Publish Date".

now i want to use the modern experience, as if in classic mode i can simply add a script editor web part and do the validation using javascript. but what are the options i have to do this validation in modern experience ? and can i benefit from list or field validation to do such a validation (as list/field validation will work on modern UI)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a list validation formula. I'll reword your request to make sure we are talking about the same thing:

> Status cannot be 'Closed' if 'Publish Date' is blank.

- Go to List Settings, and click Validation settings.
- Enter a formula similar to this one:

  =NOT( AND( ISBLANK( [Publish Date] ), [Status] = "Closed" ) )
- Enter an error message.

Comment: thanks a lot.. this worked well for me..